# Contador de idades

Tags: visualg

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo certo?

Estou com um exercício aqui da faculdade de Algoritmos I, segue o enunciado abaixo:

***Escreva um algoritmo que solicite a idade de várias pessoas (UTILIZE O REPITA). Informe o total de pessoas com menos de 25 anos e o total de pessoas com mais de 50 anos. O programa termina quando idade for negativa (Não deve ser utilizada na contagem).***

Fiz o código até o momento, apenas a repetição. Estou com dúvida em como fazer a verificação das idades para informar os totais.

Código até o momento:

```
algoritmo "APS05"
var
   idade:inteiro

inicio

      repita
            escreva("Idade: ")
            leia(idade)
      ate (idade<0)

fimalgoritmo
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

**[RESOLUÇÃO]**

```
repita
            escreva("Idade: ")
            leia(idade)

            se (idade>=0) e (idade<25) entao
               contMenos25 <- contMenos25 + 1
            fimse
            se (idade>50) entao
               contMais50 <- contMais50 + 1
            fimse

      ate (idade<0)

      escreval("Menores que 25: ", contMenos25)
      escreval("Maiores que 50: ", contMais50)
```

Comment: Uma pequena correção no seu código: não esqueça de testar `se (idade >= 0 e idade < 25)` para evitar que ele inclua na contagem as idades negativas, conforme o enunciado do exercício.

Comment: Mas eu colocar o `ate (idade<0)` não resolve isso?

Comment: Não resolve porque se digitar idade negativa vai entrar no if antes de testar o idade < 0.

Comment: Perfeitinho agora então. Mais uma vez obrigado pela sua correção e explicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa de uma variável `contadorMenosDe25Anos` de tipo inteiro que começa valendo zero e seja incrementada em um cada vez que ler uma idade entre 0 e 25 anos. Da mesma forma uma variável `contadorMaisDe50Anos` para idades maiores que 50 anos.

Depois da repetição é só imprimir o valor dessas variáveis.

Comment: Está quase lá. Lembre-se que os incrementos devem ser feitos dentro do laço de repetição e devem ser na forma `contMenos25 = contMenos25 + 1` (que é a mesma coisa que `contMenos25++`).

Comment: Mas eu coloco elas dentro de um _if_ depois do repita? Não entendi bem. A variável foi criada, mas não sei onde eu aplico ela.

Comment: Coloque num `if` depois do `leia(idade)`.

Comment: Resolvido amigão, vou postar editar o post com a resolução.

Comment: Ok, só não apague o código da pergunta original, coloque o novo código embaixo do velho. :)

Comment: Feito.
Agradeço a paciência de qualquer forma. Como sou novo aqui no stack... Eu devo fazer algum procedimento além de postar a resolução? Elogiar resposta, algo do tipo?

Comment: Se a resposta lhe atendeu, você pode aceitá-la clicando no "v" do canto superior esquerdo da mesma.

Comment: E quanto tiver mais pontos poderá também dar +1 em qualquer resposta que achar útil e correta. Sucesso!